# determine whether the series converges or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

let my series be $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{|a + \sqrt n \cdot b + n \cdot c|}$ I have to find out whether or not these converge.
I went ahead and named my sequence as $a_n=\frac{1}{|a + \sqrt n \cdot b + n \cdot c|} = \frac{1}{|n| \cdot |\frac{a}{n} + \frac{\sqrt n \cdot b}{n}  + c|}  = \frac{1}{|n| \cdot |\frac{a}{n} + \frac{b}{\sqrt n}  + c|} $ and i got $b_n$ sequence such as $b_n = \frac{1}{|n|}$ in order to use the limit criterion but I could not get to the point of succeeding with it. Could i get some help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c\neq0$,

$$a_n = \dfrac{1}{n |a/n+b/\sqrt{n}+c|} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\sim} \dfrac{1}{n|c|}$$

And $\displaystyle \sum \dfrac{1}{n |c|}$ is divergent (harmonic series) therefore $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ is divergent by comparison.

For $c = 0$, and $b\neq0$,

$$a_n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\sim} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}|b|}$$

And $\displaystyle \sum \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n} |b|}$ is divergent as a Riemann's sum with $1/2\le1$ so by comparison $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ is divergent.

For $c \neq0$ and $b \neq 0$ then $\sum a_n$ is clearly divergent.

---

In any case, $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ is divergent.

Comment: in the first case where c is not $0$ how exactly i use the comparison test. By removing things from the fractal we dont know whether or not it is getting bigger or smaller therefore i cant write $ a_n \le \frac{1}{n |c|}$

Comment: The comparison test states that if $0 < a_n \le b_n$ then if $b_n$ converges then $a_n$ converges or the opossite for divergence. How exactly do i know that the fractal isnt get bigger or smaller by removing $a/n $ and$ b/ \sqrt n$ so that i can use the creterion

Comment: Do you know the **limit comparison test**?

Comment: oh yes sorry im dumb i dont know why i stuck on the comparison test when my question was all about the limit one haha sorry for wasting your time mate and thanks for the help i should be able to understand the exercise now.

Comment: @nikosligmas No problem, I am glad I could help.